# AsyncFileUpload hasFile is always false

Tags: c#, ajax, asyncfileupload

I know with FileUploader you need to do a full post back.  But I thought with AsyncFileUpload didn't work this way.  My hasFile is always returning false. (I upload an image, and then I hit the form submit button, to find out my asyncFileUpload returns false)

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="200px" ToolTip="Upload Image" 
                OnClientUploadComplete="showUploadConfirmation"
                ThrobberID="Throbber" UploaderStyle="Traditional" runat="server" 
                OnClientUploadError="showUploadError"
                OnClientUploadStarted="checkExtension" 
                onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete"  />
```

Comment: hmm, I think maybe I should be checking the hasFIle on the OnUploadedComplete... which means I wouldn't even need the check... which makes this a lot easier... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! Basically the file already is uploaded(right after I click a file), so when I try a submit on the form there is nothing there anymore.  Ajax is too sneaky for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything in your PageLoad if yes you should wrap the code in

```
 if(!this.IsPostBack) 
 {
    do something whatever that is you do with AsyncUploader
 }
```